# Operator Norm of Translation Operator

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, operator-theory

Define the operator $T_a(f)\to f(\cdot +a)$ from $L^1_{\nu}\to L^1_{\nu}$ for a Borel probability measure $\nu$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Is the operator norm of $T_a$ well-known?  Ie, the quantity:
$$
\sup_{\|f\|\leq 1, f\neq 0}\,
\frac{\|T_a(f)\|}{\|f\|},
$$
where $\|\cdot\|$ is the $L^1_{\nu}$-norm and $\nu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: You cannot compute this for a general $\nu$.

Comment: Even only for Lebesgue measure would be an interesting start for me, to be honest.

Comment: For Lebesgue measure $\|T_a f\|_1=\|f\|_1$ so  the answer is $1$.

Comment: Right and if we had some $\nu$ absolutely with respect to Lebesgue measure?

Comment: Even then  there is no simple formula for the supremum. If you have some control on $\frac {h(a+x)} {h(x)}$, where $h$ is the Radon Nikodym derivative of $\nu$ w.r.t. Lebesgue measurem then you can get a bound for this supremum.

Comment: In the general case, $T_a$ is not even well defined. Note that $f \in L^1_\nu$ is an equivalence class of functions which are $\nu$-a.e.  But if $f = g$ $\nu$-a.e., you do not have $f(\cdot + a) = g(\cdot + a)$ $\nu$-a.e. And the integrability of $f(\cdot + a)$ is another issue.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy  Even if I had a bound on $h(a+x)/h(x)$ I don't see how to control $\|T_a\|_{op}$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to construct examples where $\|T_a\|$ is as big as you want. Let $\mu$ be Lebesgue measure, $b\in(0,1)$, $g\in L^1(\mu)$ positive, with $\|g\|_1=1$, $\int_{B_1(0)}g\,d\mu=b$, and $g$ supported in $B_1(0)\cup B_1(2)$. Define a Borel probability measure on $\mathbb R^n$ by 
$$
\nu(E)=\int_Eg\,d\mu. 
$$
Let $f=\tfrac1{\mu(B_1(2))}\,1_{B_1(2)}$. Let $a=2$. We have 
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^n}f\,d\nu=\frac{1-b}{\mu(B_1(2))}
$$
and
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^n}T_{2}f\,d\nu=\frac{b}{\mu(B_1(0))}.
$$
Thus
$$
\|T_2\|\geq\frac{\|T_2f\|}{\|f\|}=\frac{b}{1-b}.
$$
Taking for instance $b=\frac{m}{m+1}$ for $m\in\mathbb N$, we get 
$$
\|T_a\|\geq m. 
$$